# IF statement ignored on last loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will take 6 inputs and return smallest and largest number when its done. Problem I'm having is, during 6th loop no matter what number I input, it overwrites my _max variable ignoring condition in IF statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int     i;
    int     _min;
    int     _max;
    int     input[6];
            _min=20;
            _max=0;

    for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&input[i]);
        if(input[i]<_min)
            {_min=input[i];}
        if(input[i]>_max)
            {_max=input[i];}
        printf("min:%d max:%d\n",_min,_max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An array of size 6 goes from 0 to 5, not 1 to 6. So on the last initeration, it goes outside the array, which is a problem.

Comment: also, main should be a function with (void) argument, not (), which is treated as unknown number of integer arguments...

Comment: Oh I see,I've had wrong assumption that its actually from 0 to 6.

Comment: @user3533671 By that logic, and looking at your code, you would then be ignoring the first element of the array. But no, arrays in C start their index from zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you want... loop over all of them.

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the elements of the array are numbered from 0 to 5, not 1 to 6.

So since you defined the variables in this order:

```
int     _min;
int     _max;     <----
int     input[6];
```

...when you write to `input[6]`, you are actually writing to the memory just after `input[5]`, which is occupied by `_max`. I guess if you wrote to `input[7]`, you'd see the same thing happening to your `_min`.

(Note, however, that actual variable allocation is compiler and platform dependant. Where data ends up when it **overflows the buffer** is not so easy to tell).